# Modal Not opening angularJS Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to Angular & Bootstrap, but not to programming, so bear with me.

I have a "Delete" button that I'm trying to use in a Modal to confirm the selection. The issue I'm having is that the Modal opens, asks the user "Delete Multiple Guests?", but the "form" (which contains the "Delete" button) never loads.

I got this code from elsewhere in our codebase, basically just copied and modified it. I'm really pretty lost, because as far as I can tell I've copied the code almost exactly, just changed some function names and paths.

I'm really hoping I just missed something small and that it's a quick fix. I'm happy to supply more information, just not sure what else needs to be shown.

I've injected the directive into the app, which looks something like :

```
angular.module("WT",[
     ...
     "WT.guests.forms.delete_multiple.directive",
     ...
]);
```

The function to open said modal is as follows:

```
$scope.openGuestMassDelModal = function (size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          backdrop: "static",
          controller: ["$scope", "wedding",
            function ($scope, wedding) {
              $scope.guestList = guestsToDelete.guests;
              $scope.wedding = wedding;

              $scope.isMobile = function () {
                return UsersService.mobileAndTabletCheck();
              }

              $scope.closeModal = function (reason) {
                $scope.$dismiss(reason);
              };
            }],
          templateUrl: 'v3.4.2/components/guests/modals/delete_multiple/template.html',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            guestList: $scope.guestList,
            wedding: $scope.wedding
          }
        });
      };
```

The HTML for the modal looks like:

```
    <div>
    <!--For DESKTOP Version-->
    <div ng-show = "!isMobile()">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="closeModal('dismiss')"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="icon-user-minus"></i>Delete Multiple Guests?(DESKTOP)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <guests.forms.delete_multiple ng-if="guestList && wedding" guestList="guestList" wedding="wedding"></guests.forms.delete_multiple>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

The HTML for the form mentioned above:

```
    <div>
        <form name="deleteMultiGuestForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">alertmsg : {{alert.message}}</uib-alert>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete multiple guests? (guests/forms/delete_mltiple)</p>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-cancel btn-block text-bold" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block text-bold h-40" ng-click="delete(guestList)">Delete</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The JS for the form looks like:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("WT.guests.forms.delete_multiple.directive", ["ui.bootstrap", "WT.guests.service"])

.directive("guests.forms.delete_multiple", [function () {
    ...
    <More Code>
    ...
}],
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          guestList: "=",
          wedding: "="
        },
        // templateUrl: "v3.4.2/components/guests/forms/delete_multiple/template.html"
        templateUrl: "v3.4.2/components/guests/forms/delete_multiple/template.html"

      };
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ? It looks like `<guests.forms.delete_multiple>` is directive ?

Comment: I have 2 unrelated errors - both 404s on local images. 

Should it just be:
"WT.guests.forms.delete_multiple"?

Comment: Potentially I'm not sure how your directive is setup.

Comment: Please console errors and if not then check !isMobile() is satisfied or not.